# How to show iPad keyboard?

Tags: ipad

I am developing a game, a word game. I have UIView, in this I have to show the keyboard, without using UITextField. Could you please suggest me something on how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

There is no API for the keyboard. You have to go through a text input UI element. You could write your own on-screen keyboard but don't forget about Bluetooth keyboard users.

Also this isn't game dev specific. See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472258/iphone-keyboard-without-textview